# checkForm() only enters the first if()

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to make a register formular and it should only be posted after checking that all inputs a correct/ possible. So I found a nice german Tutorial here:

http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/beispiele/formulareingaben.htm

..and tried to take the things i need from it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm(){
        if(document.getElementById("email").value =="" || eMailToCheck.indexOf("@") == -1){
            alert("Bitte Emailadresse eingeben");
            document.getElementById("email").focus();
            return false;
        }

        if(document.getElementById("username").value ==""){
            alert("Bitte Usernamen eingeben");
            document.getElementById("username").focus();
            return false;
        }

        if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value != document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value)){
            alert("Passwörter stimmen nicht überein");
            document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
            return false;
        }

        if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value == "") || (document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value == "")){
            alert("Bitte beide Passwortfelder ausfüllen");
            document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
            return false;
        }

        if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value.length < 8) || (document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value.length < 8)){
            alert("Passwort muss mind. 8 Zeichen beinhalten");
            document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
            return false;
        }

    }
</script>
```

in the head of the html and call it by

```
<form action="profile.html" onsubmit="return checkForm()" method="post" name="Formular">
```

the effect is impressive:

The function is called and the first if()-block is entered. But only if i have another if() or nothing in the next line. If i have an unconditioned command in the line, it doesn't work anymore.

Only the email verification works, all others are not entered. And i don't get, why! Could someone tell me please?

EDIT: Here is my complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BlackJackX</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkForm(){
        var flag = true; 
            if(document.getElementById("email").value =="" || eMailToCheck.indexOf("@") == -1){
                alert("Bitte Emailadresse eingeben");
                document.getElementById("email").focus();
                flag=false;
            }
            else if(document.getElementById("username").value ==""){
                alert("Bitte Usernamen eingeben");
                document.getElementById("username").focus();
                flag=false;
            }
            else if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value != document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value)){
                alert("Passwörter stimmen nicht überein");
                document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
                flag=false;
            }
            else if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value == "") || (document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value == "")){
                alert("Bitte beide Passwortfelder ausfüllen");
                document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
                flag=false;
            }
            else if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value.length < 8) || (document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value.length < 8)){
                alert("Passwort muss mind. 8 Zeichen beinhalten");
                document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
                flag=false;
            }

            return flag;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:300px; height:175px; background-color:#DDDDDD; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:150px; align:center;">
        <p>
        <p>
        <form action="profile.html" onsubmit="return checkForm()" method="post">
            <table align="center">
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:right; width:25px; color:red">
                        <p id="emailValid" name="emailValid"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Emailadresse:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" size="15" maxlength="25" onblur="validateEmail()">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:right; color: red">
                        <p id="usernameValid" name="usernameValid"></p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Username:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="username" id="username" type="text" size="15" maxlength="25" onblur="validateUsername()">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:right; color:red" id="passwordOneValid" name="password1Valid">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Passwort:    
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input style="25px" name="passwordOne" id="passwordOne" type="password" size="15" maxlength="16" style="height: 25px" onblur="validatePasswordOne()">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:right; color:red" id="passwordTwoValid" name="passwordTwoValid">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        ..wiederholen:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input style="25px" name="passwordFieldTwo" id="passwordTwo" type="password" size="15" maxlength="16" style="height: 25px" onkeyup="validatePasswordTwo()">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" style="width: 92px" value="Registrierung">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>                            
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function validateEmail(){
            var eMailToCheck = document.getElementById("email").value;
            if(eMailToCheck!="" && eMailToCheck.indexOf("@") != -1){
                document.getElementById("emailValid").innerHTML = "";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("emailValid").innerHTML = "!";
            }
        }

        function validateUsername(){
            var usernameToCheck = document.getElementById("username").value;
            if(usernameToCheck != ""){
                document.getElementById("usernameValid").innerHTML = "";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("usernameValid").innerHTML = "!";
            }
        }

        function validatePasswordOne(){
            var pwToCheck = document.getElementById("passwordOne").value;
            if(pwToCheck != ""){
                document.getElementById("passwordOneValid").innerHTML = "";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("passwordOneValid").innerHTML = "!";
            }
            if(pwToCheck.length < 8 && pwToCheck != ""){
                document.getElementById("passwordOneValid").innerHTML = "8 >";
            }
        }

        function validatePasswordTwo(){
            var pwToCheck = document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value;
            if(pwToCheck != document.getElementById("passwordOne").value){
                document.getElementById("passwordTwoValid").innerHTML = "!=";
            }
            else if(pwToCheck == document.getElementById("passwordOne").value){
                document.getElementById("passwordTwoValid").innerHTML = "";
            }
        }
        </script>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use "else if" except for the first if condition and putting "else true;" at the end should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return in the end of your function, otherwise it exits too early (return exits it).

```
function checkForm(){
      var result = true;
        if(document.getElementById("email").value =="" || eMailToCheck.indexOf("@") == -1){
            alert("Bitte Emailadresse eingeben");
            document.getElementById("email").focus();
            result=false;
        }

        if(document.getElementById("username").value ==""){
            alert("Bitte Usernamen eingeben");
            document.getElementById("username").focus();
            result=false;
        }

        if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value != document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value)){
            alert("Passwörter stimmen nicht überein");
            document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
            result=false;
        }

        if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value == "") || (document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value == "")){
            alert("Bitte beide Passwortfelder ausfüllen");
            document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
            result=false;
        }

        if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value.length < 8) || (document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value.length < 8)){
            alert("Passwort muss mind. 8 Zeichen beinhalten");
            document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
            result=false;

        }
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt solve my problem.. i feel stupid right now: I changed the code but now it still submits, if only the email adress is okay. moreover it has 4 alerts in a row, when i dont fill in nothing

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse it will only enter the first if, since there is a return statement in every if condition. Put a return statement at the end. Change your code to this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkForm(){
   var flag=true;
        if(document.getElementById("email").value =="" || eMailToCheck.indexOf("@") == -1){
            alert("Bitte Emailadresse eingeben");
            document.getElementById("email").focus();
            flag= false;
        }

        if(document.getElementById("username").value ==""){
            alert("Bitte Usernamen eingeben");
            document.getElementById("username").focus();
            flag= false;
        }

        if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value != document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value)){
            alert("Passwörter stimmen nicht überein");
            document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
           flag= false;
        }

        if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value == "") || (document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value == "")){
            alert("Bitte beide Passwortfelder ausfüllen");
            document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
           flag= false;
        }

        if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value.length < 8) || (document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value.length < 8)){
            alert("Passwort muss mind. 8 Zeichen beinhalten");
            document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
            flag= false;
        }

return flag;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: sry that was a typo, fixed it

Comment: But if a user submits a form , then the page refreshes, and also the variable will reset..so maybe the code was correct in first place.

Comment: this will not be case since we are stopping form to be submitted means stopping page to refresh as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for error in last if it exists then `return false` otherwise let form be submitted. See this will work for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkForm(){
        var errorCounter=0;
        if(document.getElementById("email").value =="" || document.getElementById("email").value.indexOf("@") == -1){
            alert("Bitte Emailadresse eingeben");
            document.getElementById("email").focus();
            errorCounter++;
        }

        if(document.getElementById("username").value ==""){
            alert("Bitte Usernamen eingeben");
            document.getElementById("username").focus();
            errorCounter++;
        }

        if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value != document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value)){
            alert("Passwörter stimmen nicht überein");
            document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
            errorCounter++;
        }

        if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value == "") || (document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value == "")){
            alert("Bitte beide Passwortfelder ausfüllen");
            document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
            errorCounter++;
        }

        if((document.getElementById("passwordOne").value.length < 8) || (document.getElementById("passwordTwo").value.length < 8)){
            alert("Passwort muss mind. 8 Zeichen beinhalten");
            document.getElementById("passwordOne").focus();
            errorCounter++;
        }
        if(errorCounter>0)
            return false;
    }
</script>
```

**Edit:** Actually the problem was `eMailToCheck.indexOf("@")` here where `eMailToCheck` wasn't defined but was being used so I just changed it to `document.getElementById("email").value.indexOf("@")` and it solved problem.

Comment: sorry, this still doesnt work for me.. i dont get it. Is it possible that the error is somewhere else? For that reason i psted my whole code in the question now.

Comment: @raptus93:- Its working fine now, I have pasted your code here and tested it, everything works fine http://jsfiddle.net/8gnVw/ .

Comment: no its still not working @Mustafasabir see after filling only email id form is being submitted. Since you have that error that I have already mentioned in my edit.

Comment: Updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8gnVw/1/ .. added this line in checkform() ... var eMailToCheck = document.getElementById("email").value;

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if(document.getElementById("email").value =="" || eMailToCheck.indexOf("@") == -1){
```

to:

```
if(document.getElementById("email").value =="" || document.getElementById("email").value.indexOf("@") == -1){
```

Comment: you are right serg other problem is in this statement. @Mustafasabir OP is not defining any variable in that `checkform()` function.

Comment: Op has defined variable in  function validateEmail(), but not in checkform() ,But is using it on both places, its really confusing code. Thanks for pointing out.